# UITableView Prototype cell not found

Tags: swift, prototype, cell

every one.
After lots of search and different test my code doesn't work yet...

I try to do a simple UITableView with a simple Prototype cell whit using "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier" but this function doesn't found my Prototype Cell.

My code :

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class DanceClubViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableViewSound: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableViewSound.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellVote")
    self.tableViewSound.dataSource = self
    self.tableViewSound.delegate = self
    self.tableViewSound.reloadData()
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}    

@IBAction func backToViewPlay(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)        
}

func tableView(tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int)->Int
{
    return 10
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell : UITableViewCell = self.tableViewSound.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellVote") as UITableViewCell

    return cell
}
```

If anyone had already had this problem?

The identifier for my Prototype Cell is : cellVote

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: the exception ?  The code works, I can debug on the simulator, the code go well in func "cellForRowAtIndexPath" but my cells don't take the aspect of my 'cellVote'. And when I try to add this line : `var num: UILabel = cell.viewWithTag(1) as UILabel` the app crash and said me than can't add nil to a UILabel ... But I have well a UILabel in my cell on my storyboard. And with the good tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to address your label is to create a custom TableViewCell class in another file:

```
import UIKit

class DanceCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var num: UILabel!  //connect the label

}
```

Then for your ViewController:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class DanceClubViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewSound: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableViewSound.dataSource = self
        self.tableViewSound.delegate = self
        self.tableViewSound.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    @IBAction func backToViewPlay(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }


    func tableView(tableViewSound:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int)->Int
    {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(tableViewSound: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableViewSound.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellVote", forIndexPath: indexPath) as DanceCell

        cell.num.text = "Hello"

        return cell
    }
}
```

I removed some stuff, and added he key line in the 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' function to register the cell.  I then was able to communicate with the label.  Make sure the prototype cell has set 'cellVote' as the identifier in at attributes inspector.